# Why does my JavaFX button have strange symbols instead of text?

Tags: java, string, button, javafx

I am trying to learn JavaFX and just stumbled across something I'm confused about.  I created a new project in IntelliJ and added a single button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Button firstButton;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        firstButton = new Button("My First Button");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(firstButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I create the button with text it adds symbols instead of the text.
[Window with "My First Button" as commanded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmifP.png).

When I change the text to something small (I was thinking that it was erroring if the text was longer than the button length) it got even stranger.  This is the next example I tried:

`firstButton = new Button("E");`

And the text I got was: [Window with "E" as commanded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV05q.png).

I have Googled a bunch and have not found anyone talking about this.  Either I'm a bad Googler or it's not a common problem.  My initial thought was that it was an encoding issue.  After I saw the mystery E -> G though I'm thinking there might be something else off.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Note: If the FXML-related code is not relevant then please remove it.

Comment: This behaviour sounds like something goes wrong with the font. Does this change, if you manually specify the font to something other than the default one? Also please provide more info on the version of java(fx) you're using and about the OS. I've never seen behaviour like this on windows...

Comment: @fabian I think that was it.  When I use a system font (Such as Arial or Verdana) it works fine.  When I use an install font (such as Open Sans or Montserrat) it gives me that issue.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
```

You can do something like this:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'serif'");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```